# How can I write an array of normalized float values to AIFF using coreAudio?

Tags: c++, xcode, audio, core-audio, audiotoolbox

I've tried the following code, but on executing it gives the 'fmt?' error which tells me that 'the data format is not supported by this file type'. Unfortunately, I can't find a reference anywhere that explains how the AudioStreamBasicDescription should be set up if to write to an AIFF.

I've googled the issue and read all the documentation I can find, but to no avail. Has anybody done this kind of thing before? Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
//  This path is just for testing
char * filePath = "/Users/user/Desktop/reverb.aiff";

//  This value will actually be set by earlier code depending on how many mics are defined    
int channels = 1;

CFURLRef audioFileURL = CFURLCreateFromFileSystemRepresentation(NULL,
                                                                (const UInt8 *)filePath,
                                                                strlen(filePath),
                                                                false);

AudioStreamBasicDescription audioFileDescription = {0};
audioFileDescription.mFormatID         = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
audioFileDescription.mFormatFlags      = kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsFloat | kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsBigEndian;
audioFileDescription.mBitsPerChannel   = sizeof(float) * 8;
audioFileDescription.mChannelsPerFrame = channels;
audioFileDescription.mBytesPerFrame    = (audioFileDescription.mBitsPerChannel / 8) * audioFileDescription.mChannelsPerFrame;
audioFileDescription.mFramesPerPacket  = 1;
audioFileDescription.mBytesPerPacket   = audioFileDescription.mBytesPerFrame * audioFileDescription.mFramesPerPacket;

AudioFileID audioFileID = 0;

OSStatus createFileStatus = AudioFileCreateWithURL(audioFileURL,
                                                   kAudioFileAIFFType,
                                                   &audioFileDescription,
                                                   kAudioFileFlags_EraseFile,
                                                   &audioFileID);

if (createFileStatus != 0) {
    cout << "Error creating output file" << endl;
    cout << "Error code: " << createFileStatus << ", ";

    //  hacky way of converting number back to kinda-readable enum code
    char chars[5];
    for (int i = 3; i >= 0; i--) {
        chars[i] = (char)createFileStatus;
        createFileStatus = createFileStatus >> 8;
    }
    char[4] = '\0';
    cout << chars << endl;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: at a glance: try adding `kAudioFormatFlagIsBigEndian` to your format flags

Comment: Have done, but no change to output on recompile, unfortunately.

Comment: Change of plan - I'm just going to use a simpler library like WRAIFFPP because I'm lazy.

Comment: Do you really want to use 32-bit floats in your AIFF?

Comment: Ideally, yeah. That way I can downsample to 16-bit or 24-bit if necessary, and I can generate all the data as values between +/- 1.0

Answer (score 1):

Float data isn't supported by the AIFF type, you need to create an AIFF-C file. So when you call `AudioFileCreateWithURL` you use `kAudioFileAIFCType`.

Big endian and float are mutually incompatible, don't spec bigEndian.